# How get a custom tag with html agility pack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Need to create a summary/indice

For this I have tags `<Document-Title> My Title </Document-Title>`

How  I get these tags using HTML agility pack?

I have tried this:

```
 HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
  html.Load(new StringReader(Document.Content)); //Is the <html> I'm load in database

  var titles = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//Document-Title");
```

But titles is null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `//document-title` , it jsut need to be lowercase, HAP lowercases the tags by default, i believe the reason is that xHTML required the tag names to be lower-case, so HAP probably considered that, but its not specific to standard HTML, its fine to use tags with capitalization.

**Update:** after some research lower case is an xpath requirement, HAP is case insenstive on its own and does not care about XHTML.

Comment: @Rod updated the answer for the reason which is guess is the case.

Comment: Thanks - you've just saved me a few hours of craziness.