# HtmlAgilityPack how parse the *ngFor?

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a HtmlAgilityPack related question

Here is the html code

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-header">
    <div class="templateclass">
      <p-tabView [activeIndex]="activeTabIndex">
        <p-tabPanel *ngFor="let note of notes" [header]="note.noteName">
          <perfect-scrollbar class="ps-scroll">
            <div class="progressbarStyle">
              <p-progressBar [value]="note?.percentageCompleted"></p-progressBar>
            </div>
            <div [innerHTML]="note?.getDisplayHtml()">
            </div>
          </perfect-scrollbar>
        </p-tabPanel>
      </p-tabView>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code in C#

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
string htmlData = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlData);
IEnumerable<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode> tagNodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p-tabPanel");
```

Why return the SelectNodes always with null?

I tried to find the following p-tabView, p-tabPanel, perfect-scrollbar, p-progressBar and div, I just got valuable result for perfect-scrollbar and div

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

It's working if you search only with lower cases:

```
IEnumerable<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode> tagNodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p-tabpanel");
```

The nodes you didn't get have all an upper case: `p-tabView`, `p-tabPanel` and `p-progressBar`.

Stack Overflow references:

- [HTML Agility Pack Parsing With Upper & Lower Case Tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5779664/1351076)
- [How get a custom tag with html agility pack?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28996793/1351076)

I didn't find any official references in the [W3C XPath 1.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/).

Comment: I would never have thought this, it is not case sensitive.Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help. You can then validate the answer if it resolved your issue ;)