# Get Custom Html tag using HTML Agility Pack c#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Given I have the following HTML, how can I use HTML Agility Pack to get the value **18.2099**

I had a look at the following
[How get a custom tag with html agility pack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995014/how-get-a-custom-tag-with-html-agility-pack) but that did not work.

```
<div class="last-price">
    <div class="last u-up">
        <bdo class="last-price-value js-streamable-element" dir="ltr" data-s="100">18.2099</bdo>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Current Code***

```
var htmlText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
    
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlText);

var htmlTestNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//dbo"); <-- This returns null
var htmlNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='last u-up']/dbo[@class='last-price-value']");
if (decimal.TryParse(htmlNode.InnerText, out var value))
{
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Is it "dbo" or "bdo"? Tag says one, you search for the other

Comment: Noways, I made a spelling mistake. :( thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

this might work

```
var htmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div/div/bdo");

if (decimal.TryParse(htmlNode.InnerText, out var value))
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Or

```
var htmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//bdo[@class='last-price-value js-streamable-element']");

if (decimal.TryParse(htmlNode.InnerText, out var value))
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Comment: I actually tried both of the above, previously but as Hans pointing out I made a spelling mistake it is bdo and not dbo